# Multiple Google Charts in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, google-visualization

Hey guys I have the following problem:
I need to connect to an Oracle database with ASP.NET and get some data from this database. Then I need to display these results in Google Charts.So I made 15 different pages, each page will actually contain a database query (in graphical form,google charts and its table). I can't seem to display the data, there will always be jquery errors or something similar. I know that the javascripts go to the Site.Master page (this is where the head tag is) and I get this error which is probably not the only one and not solve my problem but I can't continue!

```
Uncaught Error: Container is not defined
```

EDIT: Fixed the above error, but there is no data displayed! The table says "Table has no columns" but the SQL Query is correct, so I assume the List returned by the WebMethod is not a JSON String or I should not return a List object (?)

Here is my Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="GoogleCharts_MondialDB.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %></title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- κάνουμε load τα google charts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'table'] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    /* φτιάχνουμε για κάθε chart συναρτήσεις
     αυτή η συνάρτηση σε javascript πέρνει τα δεδομένα που πήρε από τη συγκεκριμένη μέθοδο στη C# (που επιστρέφει τα δεδομένα των queries
        της βάσης) και τα στέλνει στη συνάρτηση drawchart από κάτω που με βάση αυτά τα δεδομένα θα φτιάξει τα charts
        και τα tables */

        function drawChart() {
            var jsonData_s2;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Simple2.aspx/GetSimple2Data',
                data: '{}',
                success: function (data) {
                    jsonData_s2 = data.d;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
                }
            });
                   var s2 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData_s2);
                    // θέλουμε και table και chart, και τα δυο τα βρισκονται στα αντιστοιχα div
                    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_s2'));
                    table.draw(s2, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('col_s2'));
                    chart.draw(s2,
                      {
                          title: "Απλό Ερώτημα 2",
                          position: "top",
                          fontsize: "14px",
                          chartArea: { width: '50%' },
                      });
                    var jsonData_s4;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        url: 'Simple4.aspx/GetSimple4Data',
                        data: '{}',
                        success: function (data) {
                            jsonData_s4 = data.d;
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
                        }
                    });
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData_s4);
            // θέλουμε και table και chart, και τα δυο τα βρισκονται στα αντιστοιχα div
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_s4'));
            table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_s4'));
            chart.draw(data,
              {
                  title: "Απλό Ερώτημα 4",
                  position: "top",
                  fontsize: "14px",
                  chartArea: { width: '50%' },
              });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'Simple6.aspx/GetSimple4Data',
                data: '{}',
                success: function (data) {
                    jsonData = data.d;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
                }
            });
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData_s6);
            // θέλουμε και table και chart, και τα δυο τα βρισκονται στα αντιστοιχα div
            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_s6'));
            table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%' });
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('col_s6'));
            chart.draw(data,
              {
                  title: "Απλό Ερώτημα 6",
                  position: "top",
                  fontsize: "14px",
                  chartArea: { width: '50%' },
              });
        }
    </script>  
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" style="background-color: #0099FF">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Font-Size="Large" StaticSelectedStyle-Font-Bold="true"> 
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Simple2" NavigateUrl="~/Simple2.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Simple4.aspx" Text="Simple4" Value="Simple4"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Simple6.aspx" Text="Simple6" Value="Simple6"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Simple8.aspx" Text="Simple8" Value="Simple8"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Simple10.aspx" Text="Simple10" Value="Simple10"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Simple12.aspx" Text="Simple12" Value="Simple12"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard2.aspx" Text="Hard2" Value="Hard2"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard4.aspx" Text="Hard4" Value="Hard4"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard6.aspx" Text="Hard6" Value="Hard6"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard8.aspx" Text="Hard8" Value="Hard8"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard10.aspx" Text="Hard10" Value="Hard10"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard12.aspx" Text="Hard12" Value="Hard12"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard14.aspx" Text="Hard14" Value="Hard14"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard16.aspx" Text="Hard16" Value="Hard16"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Hard18.aspx" Text="Hard18" Value="Hard18"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <!-- <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li> -->
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <!--<asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" /> -->
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this master page I make the work for the three pages that need google charts.
All the tutorials make google charts with one only chart so I assumed this is the way to add many charts on a page. Next is the first page's asp.net file and then the c# code behind. I use a webmethod as described in all the tutorials.

Simple2.aspx

```
%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Simple2.aspx.cs" Inherits="GoogleCharts_MondialDB._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <span style="font-size: 29pt; color: #FFFFFF"><strong>ΟΠΤΙΚΟΠΟΙΗΣΗ ΔΕΔΟΜΕΝΩΝ ΤΗΣ MONDIAL DATABASE ΜΕ ΧΡΗΣΗ GOOGLE CHARTS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong></span><img src="GDlogo2.png" id="gdlogo" alt="Google Developers Logo" /><hr />

    <div class="row">
            <h2 style="color: #FFFFFF">ΜΕΡΟΣ Ι) ΑΠΛΑ ΕΡΩΤΗΜΑΤΑ (ΖΥΓΟΣ ΑΡΙΘΜΟΣ)</h2> <hr />
            <p style="color: #FFFFFF">2. Να βρεθούν οι ποταμοί, οι λίμνες εκβολής και το μήκος των ποταμών μου εκβάλλουν μόνο σε λίμνες (όχι θάλασσα).</p>
            <div id="col_s2" style="width:300px;height:300px">
                <!-- Εδώ θα φορτώσει το chart -->
            </div>
             <div id="table_s2" style="width:300px;height:300px">
                <!-- Εδώ θα φορτώσει το table -->
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Simple2.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace GoogleCharts_MondialDB
{
    public class Simple2Data
    {
        public String river = "";
        public String lake = "";
        public float river_len = 0;

        public Simple2Data(String s1, float f1, String s2)
        {
            river = s1;
            lake = s2;
            river_len = f1;
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<Simple2Data> GetSimple2Data()
        {
            String oradb = "DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/XE;USER ID=SYSTEM";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            conn.Open();
            string cmdstr = "SELECT RIVER.NAME, RIVER.LENGTH, LAKE.NAME FROM RIVER, LAKE, RIVERTHROUGH WHERE RIVER.NAME = RIVERTHROUGH.RIVER AND LAKE.NAME = RIVERTHROUGH.LAKE AND RIVER.SEA IS NULL";
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdstr, conn);
            List<Simple2Data> dataList = new List<Simple2Data>();
            String river = "";
            String lake = "";
            float river_len = 0;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                river = dr.GetString(0);
                river_len = dr.GetFloat(1);
                lake = dr.GetString(2);
                dataList.Add(new Simple2Data(river, river_len, lake));

            }
            //conn.Close();
            //conn.Dispose();
            return dataList;
        }
    }

    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

There are no problems with the queries, they are tested and working, I can't figure out how to display the data in google charts.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error: `Container is not defined` is from google chart.
It refers to the HTML element the chart should be assigned to...
Apparently, it cannot find the container.

Try loading google like this, wait for the DOM to load first...

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadGoogle, false);

function loadGoogle() {
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart', 'table'], callback: drawChart});
}
```

Comment: I get the same error. Is it correct to load the google charts from the sitemaster page (<head> tag) and reference the divs from the other aspx files? Maybe Google Charts needs that both the <div> tag of the chart and the functions that draw them to be on the same aspx page? But that means we should call google.load function on each page, is this correct? Thanks

Comment: I actually fixed this error, the error was caused by the problem I stated above! I simply placed the function inside the aspx page. (Not all the functon, just for the "s2" chart) and that means I will need to call google.load on each aspx page. Now the problem is that the DataTable has no columns! My SQL query is correct and has ok data maybe there is something wrong with Javascript or C# code? Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: please edit the question with string version of json data, this will help tremendously

Comment: The data is returned as a List<Simple2Data> and in theory the WebMethod that returns this List automatically converts the data to JSON String. Maybe there is something wrong in the C# code but I can't find any. I tested it and the drawChart() function which calls the ajax call is successful! but the JSON data is "undefined" so there must be something wrong in C# code I assume. (SQL Code is correct though). Thanks